# h2o instance shut down due to inactive in console

Tags: instance, h2o

I am using H2O to develp model. After initiated H2O instance I got an IP and port for opening H2O flow in web browser. I used below command in HDFS to initiate the H2O instance. The problem is when I run hyperparameter search, the job takes multiple hours and my shell session got inactive and will automatically log me out. This will kill the console session and H2O instance will be killed as well. I am using Rstudio interface with H2O. Is there any way to keep H2O instance longer without auto log out/shut down due to inactivity in

## start h20 cluster

hadoop jar /dsap/devl/h2o/h2o-3.10.4.1-hdp2.4/h2odriver.jar -nodes 30 -mapperXmx 8g -output /user/userid1/h2o1 -baseport 6335

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
Add the -disown flag to do exactly that.